# Probability: random student knows 2 languages.

Tags: probability

I have problem with given exercise.

We have 72 students: 52 of them knows English, 46 knows Spanish and 48 Japanese.
Calculate probability that 1 random student:

a) knows exactly 2 languages,

b) knows exactly 3 languages.

Truthfully I have no idea how to even begin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So everyone must know either English, Spanish or Japanese?

Comment: @Yuki.F It wasn't said, but I think it's safe to say that they do know at least one.

Comment: I doubt there is enough information given in the problem, as you need at the number of people in at least one overlap.

Comment: @questionasker You're surely right. I have so much trouble with this problem so I though that maybe I'm simply too stupid to understand it but I felt something was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Aight, if everyone must know either one language, why not draw a venn diagram like this? [image: venn diagram]

Note that $a + d + f + g = 52, b + d + e + g = 46, c + e + f + g = 48, a + b + c + d + e + f + g = 72$.

After solving for each of the unknowns, you need to know $d + e + f$ to answer (1), and $g$ for (2).

---

Edit: turns out I got some help from https://www.easycalculation.com/algebra/venn-diagram-3sets.php
and $d + e + f = 12 + 8 + 6 = 26, g = 24$.